# EC2 Instance of Wordpress not mapping URLs correctly

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

I'm using an AWS [EC2 micro instance](http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress) to run a wordpress blog.

I've successfully mapped a subdomain to the Elastic IP for the micro instance. After a few [minor changes](http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/bitnami-cloud/topics/remove-bitnami-landing-page), the URL I mapped to the Elastic IP (blog.example.com) opens up the wordpress home page but whenever I click on any of the wordpress links the domain changes to the AWS public DNS for that instance (http://ec2-123-45-678-910.compute-1.amazonaws.com/wordpress/).

How do I fix the URLs so that they all follow the subdomain I have setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to following command to apply the host name change to the machine.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/updateip --machine_hostname blog.example.com
```

After that the URLs were fixed.

If using a Bitnami AMI, be sure to modify the `updateip` file in `/opt/bitnami/` to something like `updateip.orig`. This prevents the hostname from being changed on reboot.

Comment: That might not stick after a reboot, though. EC2 automatically updates the machine's hostname, because it can change when the server is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there's a setting in wordpress that forces the base address of links. Or you can rewrite the servername in webserver.

Comment: Thanks, @theist. I ended up using am 'updateip' tool that was included in the install. 
I believe this went into the mysql database and made the necessary changes. Now the URLs look like they should (except for the '/wordpress' which I am still trying to get rid of).

Comment: sudo /opt/bitnami/updateip --machine_hostname blog.example.com

Comment: Offtopic: Thanks? Reward the useful answers with upvotes and select one if it's a good solution. If you have the correct solution answer your own question, this improves the site :)